# How to resume upload with AWS S3 Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 bucket for Uploading list of files, I am using MultipleFileUpload and here is my request, while uploading the files if the internet gets disconnected and again came back then uploading process is not getting updated. How can I do so when internet is coming back, it should automatically get uploaded from the last position.

```
final ObjectMetadataProvider metadataProvider = new ObjectMetadataProvider() {
            public void provideObjectMetadata(File file, ObjectMetadata metadata) {
            }
        };

        final MultipleFileUpload multipleFileUpload = transferManager.uploadFileList(HttpUrls.IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME, "photos/mint_original/", myDir_temp, upload_file, metadataProvider);
```

Comment: May [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/mobile/pause-and-resume-amazon-s3-transfers-using-the-aws-mobile-sdk-for-android/) helps you?

Comment: Thanks but I tried that already.

Answer (score 0):

The TransferManager component in the AWS Android SDK has been deprecated in favor of the TransferUtility component. The TransferUtility component allows you to pause and resume transfers. It also has support for network monitoring and will automatically pause and resume transfers when the network goes down and comes back up. Here is the link to the TransferUtility documentation - https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/storage

Comment: I am using TransferManager because by that we can upload Multiple images by using multipart option which is not available in TransferUtility class,

also the network monitoring is not working with TransferUtility class, I checked that, I am using both TransferUtility and TransferManager  classes.

TransferManager for Multiple Image upload in single request
and TransferUtility for Single Image upload request

Comment: @LovekushVishwakarma TransferUtility has had support for multipart uploads from day 1 - all requests for uploads that are greater than 5MB will automatically use multipart uploads; for smaller files, it will use non-multipart uploads. Also, I am not sure when you last tried network monitoring, but this has been an ongoing work item for the team and the last release contained some more enhancements specifically to be compliant with Oreo+ (https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/releases/tag/release_v2.11.0).  I would urge you to try it and open an github issue if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks @Bommas but my requirement in Multipart with Multiple image upload in a bunch.

Comment: @LovekushVishwakarma Maybe you can implement the multiple logic on your side ( or propose a feature request on the github forum). In any case, using TransferManager is problematic as support for it has been deprecated a few years ago - see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/aws-sdk-for-android-transfer-manager-to-transfer-utility-migration-guide/